# How do those indices operations on matrixes work in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am reviewing an algorithm for matrix multiplication in python but I am not familiar with python.
I can't figure out (or find what does the following do exactly)

```
import numpy as np  

p = A.shape[0]  
q = A.shape[1]  

A11 = A[0:p //2, 0: q // 2]  
A21 = A[p //2: p, 0: q // 2]  
A12 = A[0:p //2, q // 2 : q]  
A22 = A[p //2:p, q // 2 : q]
```

do these operations return a 2d-matrix for each line or what's going on here?

Comment: did you add `prints` for `values` and `types` n see what it returns ?

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat: I don't know how to run python programs. I just happen to review an algorithm in Python. Is it easy to set this up and inspect?

Comment: yes python is easy . you can learn it quickly . what language do you already know ?

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat: I don't really need to learn python. It is by coincidence that an algorithm from a textbook I am reviewing has a small snippet in Python and cant figure out the implementation.Is there some doc like a javadoc that describes how these indices work?

Comment: ok got it . you can use this reference for some examples to understand syntax of this program => https://towardsdatascience.com/top-python-libraries-numpy-pandas-8299b567d955   . however , what the code above does is split the given array , if i have `A = [[2,2,5,7], [1,4,3,6]]`  , then   `A11=[[2,2]`  , `A21=[[1,4]]`  , `A12=[[5,7]]`  ,  `A22=[[3,6]]`   .

Comment: @Jim of course there is: https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat: Thank you for the reference and the explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A is a matrix or a tensor. the dimensions can be extracted by looking at the `.shape`. `.shape[0]` is the length of the first dim and `.shape[1]` length of second dim, i.e. number of rows and cols. Let's just assume `A` is in fact a matrix with 2 dimensions.

You can subset a matrix via `[]` where `[ indices on first dim, indices on second dim]`.

For illustration we set `A` to `np.arange(50).reshape(10, 5)` which looks as follows [image]

**Upper left**

The first subset selects elements in the upper left, because `//` is division which floors. roughly `0 to 10 divided by two and rounded down to integer`

```
p = A.shape[0]  
q = A.shape[1]  

A11 = A[0:p //2, 0: q // 2]
```

[image]

**Lower left**

```
A21 = A[p //2: p, 0: q // 2]
```

[image]

**Lower right**

```
A[p //2:p, q // 2 : q]
```

[image]

**Upper right**

```
A[0:p //2, q // 2 : q]
```

[image]